# C# ASP Directory exists true when it doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I've got a problem checking `Directory.Exists` which always return true while directory doesn't exist. At least these are my assumptions based on the error log.

**Note:** problem is not occurring local development environment, only on production environment.

So to start of, here is the error message:

```
Message: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\home\site\wwwroot\media\cdn'.

Exception type: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Stack Trace: 
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
at CMS.AzureStorage.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
at CMS.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
at CMS.AzureStorage.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
```

Related functions (stripped down to the relevant piece of code):

```
public override string[] GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)
{
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
  if (Directory.ExistsInFileSystem(path))
  {
    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern))
      stringList.Add(Directory.GetCaseValidPath(file, new bool?()));
  }
  ...
}

public static bool ExistsInFileSystem(string path)
{
  return System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
}
```

As you can see, it is getting to `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`, but what I don't understand is how the line `if (Directory.ExistsInFileSystem(path))` is getting bypassed when directory doesn't exist?

I am very confused and hope someone can explain what is going on.

Comment: Does your application have permission to all of the files and directories that are located udner `d:\home\site\wwwroot\media\cdn`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused how this is compiling?  Unless your class is called `Directory` ?

Comment: @KennethK. the thing is that `media\cdn` path doesn't exist, that is the problem. @Jamie Rees the function `ExistsInFileSystem` is in class named `Directory`

Comment: @JamieRees [this Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Have you tried to run that code on another machine? Does it behaves the same way? According to documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.8) code looks good.

Comment: why do you wrap System.IO.Directory.Exists with a static method ExistsInFileSystem? - Try to call System.IO.Directory.Exists method instead of wrapper method

Comment: @RomanHutnyk that is my thinking as well. The class itself is a part of Kentico (tagged) and I can't edit it as it comes compiled. I have solved this by creating the directory in the file system and then removed it, which kind of explains it could be a problem with static wrapper.

Comment: Is there any reason for use of System.IO and not  CMS.IO? CMS wrapper is in place to actually take into account azure storage providers, which does seem to be in case in your application (in production at least based on stack trace) CMS provider uses IoC to register azure file mappings into the application and this could be the case, why it is resolving incorrect path in your situation directly to the application and not to storge... Take a look also at this post: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/where-did-the-system-io-namespace-go (old, but still valid)

Comment: @MichalSamuhel the code pieces attached are from `CMS.AzureStorage` class and that is what Kentico (8.2) does, not me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the folder outside of your site root folder.
If the production environment is "Cloud" then you need to provide the access to directory.

Providing access is depends on your cloud environment

1. If you are using VM then you can directly go to IIS and provide the directory access.
2. For other models you need provide access through code.

Below is code for providing read and write access to the wwwroot folder.
You can call your code after below code

```
string file = @"d:\home\site\wwwroot"; 
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```